# Used to be possible in Snow Leopard to move an app between `desktops` with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, mission-control

You could assign a keyboard shortcut to move the app with focus to a specific desktop.  Can't find this in Lion.  Anyone know if it's still possible?

Comment: Did this shortcut really exist? I don't remember seeing it.

Comment: Same here, I was never aware of such a thing existing.

Comment: I figured it out! See answer below.  Actually never changed, still works the same way as Leopard.  Hadn't used it lately since Spaces never stuck with me.  Mission Control actually seems useful so am reinvestigating how some of it's stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this.

- Open System Prefs > keyboard
- On Keyboard Shortcuts tab choose Mission Control
- Enable the "Switch to Desktop..." shortcuts
- Now when you click on a window and perform the Switch to Desktop keyboard shortcut it'll move that window to the desktop

Guess there is a mouse component to this, so it's not pure keyboard.  But I find it way easier than dragging windows around in mission control.